# Inserting a total row at the bottom of the tableviewer

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

My tableviewer looks like this:

```
Column1    Column2     Column3

John        13           NDN
Smith       14           ndn
Adam        10           ndn
```

It has a context menu on right click. Actually, I want at the right click and click on the option, to move the row at the bottom of the table. So the table will look like this, after pressing this option on the first row:

```
Column1    Column2     Column3


Smith       14           ndn
Adam        10           ndn
John        13           NDN
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to update your model (the array or list you gave to `setInput`) and then call `TableViewer.refresh()` to get the viewer to refresh the display from the updated list.

For a large table using `TableViewer.remove(row data)` followed by `TableViewer.add(row data)` instead of the `refresh()` may be faster - you still need to update the model array.

Comment: Is there a way to put in the bottom using viewer comparator ?

Comment: You could use a comparator but you would probably have to add extra data to the rows to tell the comparator the order you want.